# How can we compute solar position at a given place on a given day and time?

Tags: python, python-2.7, astronomy

I have UTC time (hours, minutes, seconds), longitude(deg E), latitude (deg N) and date. Can anyone provide me with a code to calculate solar zenith angle in Python 2.7?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is an interesting problem and I think I have a good answer - well, at least starting points.

Check out the awesome [`astropy` package](https://github.com/astropy/astropy). I believe you need to use the [`coordinates` module](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/).

Something along these lines:

```
import astropy.coordinates as coord
from astropy.time import Time
import astropy.units as u


loc = coord.EarthLocation(lon=0.1 * u.deg,
                          lat=51.5 * u.deg)
now = Time.now()

altaz = coord.AltAz(location=loc, obstime=now)
sun = coord.get_sun(now)

print(sun.transform_to(altaz).alt)
```

Here, we are getting the angle of the sun above the horizon for the `0.1` degrees longitude and `51.5` latitude location at the current time.

FYI, `.zen` would give you the zenith angle.

Comment: Why do they use their own `Time` class instead of the standard `datetime`?

Comment: @MarkRansom I think the `AltAz` expects a `Time()` instance, but not sure - still exploring the powers of the package. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response Alecxe. I hope this will be helpful for me. Thanks again

Comment: @MarkRansom - `Time` is used instead of `datetime` because `datetime` is missing many astronomy-critical features.  E.g., dynamic range of a nanosecond over Gigayear spans, conversion to/from standard astronomy forms like JD or MJD, an understanding of the UT1 to UTC conversion, numpy support, etc.

Comment: Also if for whatever reason you want to use `datetime`, you can pass it in as the obstime argument and it will auto-convert to a `Time` internally.

Comment: @eteq after I asked I started speculating it was something like that, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

@alecxe's answer is great, but I thought I'd add a slight modification that's a bit closer to what the original question is asking (the zenithal angle at a *specific time*)

```
from astropy.coordinates import get_sun, AltAz, EarthLocation
from astropy.time import Time

sun_time = Time('2017-12-6 17:00') #UTC time
loc = EarthLocation.of_address('Baltimore, MD')  # anything the google geocoding API resolves
altaz = AltAz(obstime=sun_time, location=loc)

zen_ang = get_sun(sun_time).transform_to(altaz).zen
```

`zen_ang` is then an `Angle` object - see more about those in [the docs](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/coordinates/angles.html), but basically they end up working like `numpy` scalars with associated units of "degrees".